# Give priority when replacing strings

Tags: python, regex

I am using a `Dictionary` as a way to transform keys into values for further use (here with `Pandas`).

```
abc = {"ABC":"ALPHABET"}
a = {"A":"APPLE"}

words = abc.copy()
words.update(a)

for w in words:
    df.loc[df["company"].str.contains(w), "company"] = words[w]
```

Let's use the example string: `"Company ABC"` in column `"company"`.

My problem is that when the string is supposed to give match to `"ABC":"ALPHABET"`, the dict gives precedence to `"A":"APPLE"`. This seems to be the case regardless of the order in the `dict`.

Can I make the program discern when to apply `"A:APPLE"`, for instance by making a `regex` rule that `"A"` has to be in the end of the string, as in: `"Company A"`?

Comment: "the dict gives precedence" this is not a thing, what do you mean? "the order in the `dict`" this is also not a thing, dictionaries don't have order. You can sort the keys with `sorted(words.keys())`.

Comment: @machineyearning AFAIK, there is a random order in dictionaries, but they aren't "ordered". What I mean by giving precedence is what I wrote in plain english.

Comment: If only the order is important to you, in python2.7 you can use OrderedDict from the collection library (https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: "Plain english" is not usually sufficient to describe a programming goal. When you add in keywords and jargon from a programming language interspersed liberally in your "plain english" it becomes ambiguous what you actually mean.

Comment: Try to describe your goal rather than/in addition to your problem.

Comment: @machineyearning The goal is to make the program choose the value for `"ABC"`, not `"A"` just because there is an `"A"` in `"ABC"`.

Comment: At what point are you claiming that your program is 'choosing the value for `"A"`'?

Comment: Regarding dictionary "order", it is consistent between iterations but not if you start adding/removing keys.

Comment: @machineyearning As I said: "My problem is that when the string is supposed to give match to `"ABC":"ALPHABET"`, the dict gives precedence to `"A:APPLE"`." Thanks for your anecdotal advice but I'm having a hard time believing that the purpose of the question was that unclear.

Comment: You actually have another problem there. Even if the order of the words was correct, it would act the same (since "ALPHABET" contains "A", so after the first replacement it would have been replaced again.)

Comment: Cite specific lines and explain exactly what you expect them to do, in the most explicit programming terminology you can think of. With the same formality you should explain what they do instead.

Comment: You could actually try to explain in more detail or with a different analogy, rather than react with insults. I've flagged your comment for moderator attention as "rude/offensive". Please watch your tone and refrain from insulting other users, we take our community atmosphere seriously here.

Comment: @machineyearning I have already clarified once with a specific goal, but you seem to be more about reiterating your initial point. Would be glad if you could stop trying to obfuscate the comment field and sabotage my question, please.

Comment: And I responded to your single clarification, by asking at what point you think the program is making the decision to use `"A"` rather than `"ABC"`.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote because your question was clear enough to get an acceptable answer, even if I still don't understand it because of my particular brand of autism. Cheers and have fun programming!

Comment: @machineyearning Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to replace string by other strings according to precedents. There are two things to worry about here:

1. Using a data structure that preserves the order, so regular python dictionary doesn't fit to this purpose. (You could use `collections.OrderedDict` to bypass that).
2. Changing the data while iterating. In the original code you changed the data in the middle, what would have caused the second word to be tested on the first word.

Since there is no apparent reason to actually use dictionary, I'm going to use list of tuples. At first, I create a list of queries (so they would refer the original data) and then I'm going to test the query on the data in *reversed* order, so that the words higher on the list will be the ones that matter.

```
words = [("ABC", "ALPHABET"),
         ("A", "APPLE")]

word_series = []

for word, replace in words:
    series = df["company"].str.contains(word)
    word_series.append((series, replace))

for series, replace in reversed(word_series):
    df.loc[series, "company"] = replace
```

Comment: `for series, replace in word_series:`, your `list` variable `word_series` will be empty here. I'm guessing you mean `word_series.insert` above. Also, if you want to iterate over your values in reverse order, you don't need to push them into the front of the list with `insert(0`, you can use the built-in function `reversed` like so: `for series, replace in reversed(word_series)`

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Fixed. About the reversed - I think it would be about the same regarding running time, no? (Since the list of items would be very small)

Comment: I don't think so, since `reversed` just gives you an iterator backwards over the elements, which should be constant time, O(1), overshadowed by the cost of `append`ing and traversing. On the other hand `insert` is O(n) meaning you'd get O(n^2) inserting n elements. See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Also even if the actual running time is similar because of a small number of elements, in my opinion it's more readable and pythonic to use `reversed`.

Comment: @tmrlvi Thanks for your suggestion, I am trying it out but get the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` for line `df.loc[series, "company"] = words[w]`. I'll try to find the cause.

Comment: Sorry, another typo. It should have been ```replace``` instead of ```words[w]```. (Note that it doesn't exists)

Comment: you're correct, I didn't understand the intention, comment withdrawn

Comment: @tmrlvi Thank you for your assistance! Your solution works. I was depending on dictionaries for other uses in the code, so I would've preferred that to tuples. However, this works so I will accept the answer :) I have also edited the title of the question since we did not neither `dict` or `regex`.